# Add sub menu using css in html

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to add a sub menu using css. When I hover my mouse over the a link "Top Menu", I want a sub menu to appear. See the code at [here](http://jsfiddle.net/fm7Ct/)

```
    <div id="navbar"> <span class="navbutton">
                <a id="button-1" href="#">Shop</a>
            </span>
 <span class="navbutton">
                   <a href="#">
                       Test1</a>   
                </span>
 <span class="navbutton"><a id="button-3" href="#">Top Menu</a>
    </span>
 <span class="navbutton"><a id="button-4" href="#">Test1</a>
    </span>
 <a class="linefreak"></a><a class="linefreak"></a>
 <span class="navbutton"><a id="button-5" href="#">Test2</a>  
    </span>
</div>
```

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/fm7Ct/3/)

The below should get you started- note you're likely better off using lists (`ul`, `li`) for this type of setup.

HTML

```
<ul>
    <li>Shop</li>
    <li>Test1</li>
    <li>Top Menu
        <ul>
            <li>Sub Item</li>
            <li>Sub Item</li>
            <li>Sub Item</li>
            <li>Sub Item</li>
            <li>Sub Item</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Test1</li>
    <li>Test2</li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
ul {
    list-style:none;
    background:green;
}
ul, li {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
li {
    display:inline-block;
    padding:10px 10px;
}
ul li ul {
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
}
ul li ul li {
    display:block;
}
ul li:hover ul {
    display:block;
}
```

Comment: This is not keyboard accessible but still... +1

Comment: Adding "ul li a:hover + ul{display: block;}" would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

SW4 is right.. and for your example here the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/fm7Ct/4/

```
.navbutton:hover #button-3+.submenu{
    display:inline;
}
.submenu{
    display:none;
}
```